# Postgres - UPDATE's becomes slower over time

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table like this (more columns but these will do):

```
events
+----------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+  
| event_id | user_ipaddress |   network_userid   |  domain_userid   | user_fingerprint | user_id |  
+----------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+  
|        1 | 127.0.0.1      | 000d7d9e-f3cb-4a08 | 26dc9870c3572519 |       2199066221 |         |  
|        2 | 127.0.0.1      | 000d7d9e-f3cb-4a08 | 26dc9870c3572519 |       2199066221 |         |  
|        3 | 127.0.0.1      | 000d7d9e-f3cb-4a08 | 26dc9870c3572519 |       2199066221 |         |  
|        4 | 127.0.0.1      | 000d7d9e-f3cb-4a08 | 26dc9870c3572519 |       2199066221 |         |  
+----------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
```

The table contains around 1M records. I'm trying to update all records to set the `user_id`.
I'm using a very simple PHP script for that.

I'm looping over each record with `user_id = NULL` and `SELECT` from the entire table to find existing `user_id` based on `user_ipaddress`, `network_userid`, `domain_userid` and/or `user_fingerprint`.

If nothing was found I will generate a unique `user_id` and `UPDATE` the record.
If a match was found I will `UPDATE` the record with the correspondent `user_id`.

The query looks like this:

```
UPDATE events SET user_id = 'abc' WHERE event_id = '1'
```

The `SELECT` part is super fast (~5ms).
The `UPDATE` part starts fast (~10ms) but becomes slower (~800ms) after a few hundred updates.

If I wait for around 10-20 minutes it's becomes fast again.

I'm running a PostgreSQL 9.3.3 on AWS RDS (db.m1.medium) with General Purpose SSD storage.
I have indexes on all columns combined and individually.

I have played with `FILLFACTOR` and currently it's set to `70`. I have tried to run `VACUUM FULL events`, but I never know if it finished (waited more than 1h). Also I've tried `REINDEX TABLE events`.

I'm the only one using this server.

Here's an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the `UPDATE` query:

```
Update on events  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=7479) (actual time=0.118..0.118 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using events_event_id_idx on events  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=7479) (actual time=0.062..0.065 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (event_id = '1'::bpchar)
Total runtime: 0.224 ms
```

Any good ideas on how I can keep the query fast?

Comment: Can you show an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on a long `UPADATE`?

Comment: "cost=0.43..8.45" hmmm.... [See slide 13](https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/4/45/Explaining_EXPLAIN.pdf)

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko the one in my question is from a long `UPDATE`

Comment: "indexes on all columns combined"?! Really? Are you aware that in PostgreSQL there is less need to make combined column indexes as it has some efficient algorithms to combine single-column indexes on the fly? Also, do you need all those indexes? Updating the indexes can be slow. Try to prune your indexes: http://www.databasesoup.com/2014/05/new-finding-unused-indexes-query.html

Comment: @MortenPetersen The `EXPLAIN` in your question shows `Total runtime: 0.224 ms`. Less than 1 ms. Where did you get a `800ms` figure?

Comment: @MortenPetersen This seems to be a problem with multiple connections to the DB. Can you check `SELECECT * FROM pg_stat_activity`? This query will show all open connections to the server.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko there are only three connection. The one from the script, the one make the pg_stat_activity-query and `rsdadmin`.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko I can't seem to get a much higher number running it from PGCommander. The 800ms comes from measuring times in PHP around the query.

Comment: If `PGCommander` (or better - command line `psql`) gives you normal time - profile your PHP code for possible problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was caused by the filesystem chosen for my RDS instance.
I was running with `General Purpose Storage (SSD)`. It apparently has some I/O limits. So the solution was to switch storage. Now I'm running the `Provisioned IOPS Storage` and the performance improved instantly.

Also a solution could be to stick to the `General Purpose Storage (SSD)` and increase storage size, since that would increase I/O limits as well.

Read more:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#Concepts.Storage.GeneralSSD

Thanks for all replies. And thanks to @Dan and @ArtemGr for pointing me in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Over the 10-20 minutes to become fast again, do you get a gradual improvement?

Things I'd check:

- are you creating new connections with each update and leaving them open? They would then timeout and close sometime later.
- what is the system load (CPU, memory, IO) doing? I did wonder whether the instance might support bursts, but I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, I actually see a gradual improvement. If I restart my process The first 10 updates are quite fast. Here's the stats from AWS:  

http://i.imgur.com/ZP2d6vh.png
http://i.imgur.com/1bFhCMO.png

Comment: I use the same connection for all the queries (selects, updates)

Comment: What's the filesystem? Some filesystems (e.g. BTRFS) have that kind of behavior (e.g. slowing down after accumulating a lot of writes to process). Also it might be an SSD writeback cache and you hitting its limits. Maybe something like that? http://www.howtogeek.com/165542/why-solid-state-drives-slow-down-as-you-fill-them-up/

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing,
It is because your primary key is char not int. Try to convert your primary key into int and see the result.

Your explain analyze result says `Index Cond: (event_id = '1'::bpchar)`

1. The best choice for primary key are integer data types since integer values are process faster than character data type values. A character data type (as a primary key) needs to be converted to ASCII equivalent values before processing.
2. Fetching the record on the basis of primary key will be faster in case of integers as primay keys as this will mean more index records will be present on a single page. So the total search time decreases. Also the joins will be faster. But this will be applicable incase your query uses clustered index seek and not scan and if only one table is used. In case of scan not having additional column will mean more rows on one data page.

[SQL Index - Difference Between char and int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141737/sql-index-difference-between-char-and-int)

Comment: The event_id is not an integer. I was using 1,2,3,4 to simplify. I can see know that it was a bad idea. Sorry for that. The event_id is like: fd057117-596e-4973-9eef-8fe338354820